# I need to learn some songs on ukulele for a school play, which are the easiest to begin with?

Tags: ukulele

The school play is in a month, but we'll have a rehearsal soon, so I would like to learn the most common chord for the show. I got the suggestion for the soprano tuned in high-G, but I'm new to this, need your advice.

Comment: The school issued you with a ukulele for a performance in a month without any guidance as to how to learn to play it?

Comment: The easiest ones are those with only two chords! However, which chords? You'll need to get some advice from the 'teacher' who just gave you the uke. That apart, this will be closed, as the question doesn't meet the criteria of this site. Sorry - get learning some chords..!

Comment: Welcome! We [don't cover](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) requests for resources here, but there are lots out there to be found just by searching "beginner ukulele." I *will* say that common beginner *chords* are C, F, G (or better yet G7), and A. Master those and you can play anything that uses I, IV, V(7) and vi chords, as long as you play in the key of C.

Comment: @AndyBonner - A minor would be what you mean, not A.

Comment: Funnily enough, I actually self-learned several songs on ukulele (since I'm self-taught, likely with the wrong way to hold the ukulele while playing it) - and honestly, I'd rather think about easy music in terms of easy keys (mainly ones that use multiple open strings like C major, F major, G major, and A minor) than easy chords (again, ones that use multiple open strings like C, F, Am, Am7/C) since you can get away with melody only or dyads.

Comment: You know what this means: the song you manage to putter your way through by yourself *is* the easy song to begin with. I recommend Christmas carols (quite a few of those songs I self-learned are Christmas carols), although a lot of folk songs will do.

Comment: For the new version of the question, do you have the sheet music of what you need to play? (A simple harmonic analysis should reveal the most common chord from there, assuming you actually get more than just melody lines.)

Comment: Thanks for editing! One other thing you should probably edit to clarify: Do you get to just pick a song, any song? Or are there songs already planned that you're expected to play for? Is there a theme (e.g. holiday)? (But the good news is, ukulele is an incredibly "friendly" instrument. Go ahead, google "beginning ukulele"; you'll find a million videos, charts, and pages, any one of which can teach you C, F, and G in 10 minutes.) If you do get to pick your song, then even more important than which chords it uses is how quickly and often the chords *change*.

Comment: If this is now about learning chords, then it could use an edit to the title to mention chords and it will be more likely on-topic. Hard to tell what the intended question is right now.

Comment: @AndyBonner Hi, I can pick any song, we don't have a specific theme. I found a lot of songs on this website: https://www.ukulele-tabs.com/famous-ukulele-songs, there are chords, so I assume this is what I need?

Comment: @Geezd Sure, but some of those are probably harder than others. To be honest, the first thing I did when my wife gave me a uke was search "beginning ukulele" on Youtube and in 5 minutes I knew three chords and a short song. As I mentioned, think about how long each chord lasts. For instance, if you played "Jingle Bells" in C, then you probably play C for 4 bars, but then F for 1 bar, C for 1, and G for 2. In contrast, "The First Noel" would probably change chord every bar for the first few bars. Explore, do a little trial and error!